# Pandas: update column 'E' value if column 'C' value is 'x'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like:

```
           A           B       C       D  E
0      NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD01'   'DSU'  F
1      NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD21'   'DSU'  F
2      NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD22'   'DSU'  F
3      NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD23'   'DSU'  F
4      NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD24'   'DSU'  F
5      NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD25'   'DSU'  F
6      NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD01'   'DSU'  F
7      NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACK'  'MISC'  F
8      NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACU'  'MISC'  F
9      NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACK'  'MISC'  F
10     NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACU'  'MISC'  F
11     NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACK'  'MISC'  F
12     NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACU'  'MISC'  F
13     NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACF'  'MISC'  F
14     NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ASF'  'MISC'  F
15     NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'DEF'  'MISC'  F
16     NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'RLR'   'RLR'  T
```

What I am trying to achive is when Column 'C' =='ACK' make Column 'E' = T
So far I have tried the following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd


source_folder = 'D:/NSSCDB/STTS_RCL_Export/'

def editNSPNT():

    for somefile in os.listdir(source_folder):
        if (somefile.startswith(('nsscdb_output_dts')) and 
somefile.endswith(('.txt'.lower()))):

            df = pd.read_csv(source_folder + somefile, encoding='utf-8', names = ['A','B','C','D','E'], header=4)
            #for x in df['C']:
                #if (x == 'ACK'):
                    #df['E'] = 'T'
            #df.E = ["T" if x == "ACK" for x in df.C]
            df.loc[(df.C=='ACK')]['E'] = 'T'

            print(df)



def main():

    editNSPNT()


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Neither methods I have been trying are working, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting just the [loc()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.C == "'ACK'", 'E'] = 'T'
```

The result is:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'XD01'  'DSU'   F
1   NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'XD21'  'DSU'   F
2   NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'XD22'  'DSU'   F
3   NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'XD23'  'DSU'   F
4   NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'XD24'  'DSU'   F
5   NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'XD25'  'DSU'   F
6   NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'XD01'  'DSU'   F
7   NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'ACK'   'MISC'  T
8   NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'ACU'   'MISC'  F
9   NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'ACK'   'MISC'  T
10  NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'ACU'   'MISC'  F
11  NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'ACK'   'MISC'  T
12  NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'ACU'   'MISC'  F
13  NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'ACF'   'MISC'  F
14  NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'ASF'   'MISC'  F
15  NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'DEF'   'MISC'  F
16  NSPNT   'ACTENRGY'  'RLR'   'RLR'   T
```

With your original code you are first slicing the dataframe with (not considering the simple quotes):

```
df.loc[(df.C=='ACK')]
```

Then assign a value for the sliced dataframe's column `E`.

```
['E'] = 'T'
```

In other words, you were updating the slice, not the dataframe itself.

From Pandas documentation:

> .loc[] is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean
>   array.

Breaking down the code:

```
df.loc[df.C == "'ACK'", 'E']
```

`df.C == "'ACK'"` will return a boolean array identifying the rows, and the string `'E'` will identify the column that will receive the new value, at once without slicing.

Answer (score 3):

Are the single quotes in your data causing you problems?

```
df.loc[df['C'] == "'ACK'",'E'] = 'T'
```

Use double quotes,

```
        A           B       C       D  E
0   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD01'   'DSU'  F
1   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD21'   'DSU'  F
2   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD22'   'DSU'  F
3   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD23'   'DSU'  F
4   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD24'   'DSU'  F
5   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD25'   'DSU'  F
6   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD01'   'DSU'  F
7   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACK'  'MISC'  T
8   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACU'  'MISC'  F
9   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACK'  'MISC'  T
10  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACU'  'MISC'  F
11  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACK'  'MISC'  T
12  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACU'  'MISC'  F
13  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACF'  'MISC'  F
14  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ASF'  'MISC'  F
15  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'DEF'  'MISC'  F
16  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'RLR'   'RLR'  T
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution using [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.E=np.where(df.C.eq("'ACK'"),'T',df.E)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        A           B       C       D  E
0   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD01'   'DSU'  F
1   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD21'   'DSU'  F
2   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD22'   'DSU'  F
3   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD23'   'DSU'  F
4   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD24'   'DSU'  F
5   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD25'   'DSU'  F
6   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'  'XD01'   'DSU'  F
7   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACK'  'MISC'  T
8   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACU'  'MISC'  F
9   NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACK'  'MISC'  T
10  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACU'  'MISC'  F
11  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACK'  'MISC'  T
12  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACU'  'MISC'  F
13  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ACF'  'MISC'  F
14  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'ASF'  'MISC'  F
15  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'DEF'  'MISC'  F
16  NSPNT  'ACTENRGY'   'RLR'   'RLR'  T
```